# How to Compare Two Vector Graphs in dxf use ezdxf?

Tags: vector, graph

I now have a vector graph A, a set of vector graphs S (which contains many vector graphs), and I want to find some sets of graphs X from S that share some similarities with vector graph A (assuming N vector graphs meet my needs)

As shown in the following figure, the cyan image is X, and the pink image is A. Therefore, the vector images in set X can meet the following requirements:

Assuming that two graphs share the center of a circle, vector graph A remains stationary, X rotates, and at a certain moment, X can completely cover graph A; Namely:

1. The maximum circumscribed radius of X cMaxX>cMaxA
2. The minimum circumscribed radius of X cMinX>cMinA
3. The vector graph data set of X should not intersect with the vector graph data set of A, that is, there is no intersection point

I want to implement the above ideas and inquire about the key judgments. Have you provided them in your document?

I want find it~
Thanks a lot!